# Using statsd-bridge to push data to prometheus from statsd

Tags: python, django, statsd, prometheus

I have been using statsd in my python django application for measuring different metrics. Now we have been integrating prometheus io so that we can query those metrics at later point of time. In this context, I have gone through statsd_bridge https://github.com/prometheus/statsd_bridge. I have been using it like following:

./statsd_bridge  -statsd.listen-address="localhost:9090" -statsd.mapping-config="" -web.listen-address="a.b.c.d:8125" -web.telemetry-path="/metrics"

In the above, statsd is running on a.b.c.d on port 8125 and I have set up prometheus on my local machine. But the problem is that I cannot see any of statsd metrics in prometheus i.e. http://localhost:9090/metrics. So if anyone helps me in figuring out what mistakes I am doing here I will be really grateful.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right arguments? According to https://github.com/prometheus/statsd_bridge#building-and-running `statsd.listen-address` should be the address on which to receive statsd metric lines, but you are pointing to the address where you want to see the Prometheus metrics. Check the config parameters carefully!

Comment: Author of the statsd-bridge here. @dukebody is right. The arguments need to be reversed.

Comment: Hey @Julius, it would be great to get your thoughts on the following SO question about a prometheus-to-statsd bridge  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706574/are-there-any-existing-programs-for-scraping-prometheus-formatted-metrics-and-se

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use other way, like pushgateway

some code

```
from prometheus_client import CollectorRegistry, Gauge, push_to_gateway

registry = CollectorRegistry()
g = Gauge('job_last_success_unixtime', 'Last time a batch job successfully finished', registry=registry)
g.set_to_current_time()
push_to_gateway('localhost:9091', job='batchA', registry=registry)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://github.com/prometheus/statsd_bridge#building-and-running%20statsd.listen-address) `statsd.listen-address` should be the address on which to receive statsd metric lines, but you are pointing to the address where you want to see the Prometheus metrics. The arguments need to be reversed.

Check the config parameters carefully!

Answer (score 0):

the `statsd.listen-address` will listen and collect data from **UDP**.
your should use `./statsd_bridge -statsd.listen-address=":8125" -statsd.mapping-config="" -web.listen-address="127.0.0.1:9090" -web.telemetry-path="/metrics"`
than for check http://localhost:9090/metrics